# Crashes and strange behaviour when manipulating strings

Tags: arduino

My chip just stop doing anything. sometimes it prints good results, sometimes its not, i just cant understand whats wrong with this code( and generally any time you using Strings it happens )

```
void ParseGetRequest(char* data)
{

             String parseGET=data;
             String from="GET /";
             String to="HTTP";
             int ind1 = parseGET.indexOf(from);
             int ind2 = parseGET.indexOf(to);
             parseGET=parseGET.substring(ind1+from.length(), ind2-1);
             strcpy(data, parseGET.c_str () );

}
```

And calling it with :

```
void readWifDataAsSever(char* reqData)
{

     uint8_t buffer[128] = {0};
    uint8_t mux_id;
    uint32_t len = wifi.recv(&mux_id, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 100);
     char serverData[100]={0};


    if (len > 0) 
    {

        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
           serverData[i]=(char)buffer[i];



        ParseGetRequest( serverData );    ///****** the call

        Serial.println(serverData);  // prints only part of the values
//here the chip just freeze and stop the main loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NULL termination !!!!

```
serverData[len ] = '\0';
```

Comment: Please consider adding more information to your answer. Whilst it's great you are trying to share knowledge by answering your own question, unless you include information in your answer, you aren't actually doing that.